# How could I use the Froala HTML Editor with the Ext JS Classic toolkit?

Tags: extjs

I would like to use the Froala WYSIWYG HTML Editor with Ext JS Classic Application. Could you show me how to add the Froala Editor to my Classic Application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you could add it to your Ext JS 7 Classic application.

[image: Example of how it looks]

**Directions**

Two things need to be done in order to use the Froala Editor in classic. 
1. Import the javascript resources to your application
2. Initialize the Froala editor with a TextArea

**HTML Source**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <!-- Include Editor style. -->
    <link href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/froala-editor@3.0.6/css/froala_editor.pkgd.min.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />

    <!-- Include JS file. -->
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/froala-editor@3.0.6/js/froala_editor.pkgd.min.js'></script>
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

**Javascript Source**

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Ext JS 7 Classic & Froala Example for Modern & Classic Themes',

    // You get a Froala license with the Ext JS enterprise edition.
    // Email Froala support to get your license.
    // https://wysiwyg-editor.froala.help/hc/en-us

    launch: function () {
        var editor;

        var htmlValue = '<p>The <a href="https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor">Froala Editor</a> is a lightweight WYSIWYG HTML Editor written in Javascript that enables rich text editing capabilities for your applications.</p><p><br></p><p><img src="https://www.sencha.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/built-in-support-for-rpc-requestfactory-and-json.png" style="width: 300px;" class="fr-fic fr-dib fr-fil"></p>';

        var displayHtml = function () {
            var htmlContent = editor.html.get();
            Ext.Msg.alert('Status', htmlContent);
        }

        // Once the panel is ready, render the Froala HTML Editor
        var renderEditor = function () {
            editor = new FroalaEditor('#my-froala-editor-id1', {}, function () {
              // Call the method inside the initialized event.
              editor.html.set(htmlValue);
            });
        }

        Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            fullscreen: true,
            margin: 20,
            items: [{
                xtype: 'panel',
                padding: 0,
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'textareafield',
                    id: 'my-froala-editor-id1',
                    width: '100%',
                    height: 400,
                    // Fix editor bottom clipping from panel margin...
                    margin: '0 0 80 0'
                }],
                listeners: {
                    boxready: renderEditor, // classic listener
                    painted: renderEditor, // modern listener
                }
            }, {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Display HTML',
                margin: '5 0 10 0',
                handler: displayHtml, // classic listener
                listeners: {
                    tap: displayHtml, // modern listener
                }
            }]
        });

    }
});
```

**Sencha Fiddle Example**

Tryout the code here: 
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/30hl